# How would you prevent HTML elements from moving once the console is opened

Tags: html, css

It's kind of annoying when you open up the console for your website, and all of a sudden, all the elements are jumbled up. How can you prevent this from happening?

To open the console, you would click F12.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? This is a poor quality question. Are you seeking help with responsive design of a website you are working on? Are you just using some website that's not designed well? The question is much too vague to actually provide a reasonable answer. Also, please provide code examples of what you have done. Please revise this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your console window can be "undocked", so it opens as a separate window.